# Generating dependency charts for Maven

Tags: maven, dependency-management

Are there any good tools that can scan many levels into maven projects / subprojects and generate reports or charts about all of the dependencies, version discrepancies between the same packages in different projects, etc etc?

Is there some other smart way to manage large maven projects that have several layers of subprojects with a large number of dependencies in each one?

Answer (score 2):

Get a repository manager like Nexus, use the Maven Dependency plugin, use Sonar, use Hudson/Jenkins, check out Sonatype Insight and the Insight for CI plugin, use the dependency viewer in Eclipse, use a parent pom for your organization to centralize dependency versions and so on. Lots to do for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). It has got all you need to do with a maven project.

Jenkins with sonar the best combination for managing huge maven projects.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how "deep" you want to go, the maven site builds can use the reporting plugins to generate much of what you want.  If you want much more info, then something like Sonar is probably more of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) which can produce reports either [ASCII or in different formats](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#outputType). Or you use the dependency-hierarchy in your IDE (m2e Plugin Eclipse) to look into the dependencies.